# Where is the submit button for Beta App Review (iOS)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I submitted an app for Beta review, and it was justifiably rejected because of a small error on my part.  I've fixed that error, and I want to resubmit to Beta review.  But now I don't see any way to submit.  The only option I'm given is to submit for actual App Store review. I tried adding another tester, but that didn't help.

In case my question is unclear, where is the submit button for Beta testing?

Thank you,

Eli

Comment: Upload a new build and then select at least one external tester for the build.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and correct response!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue trying to find how to do this after a rejection for a layout issue.

Go to test flight > Your testing group > Build > click the + button > Select a build > Tester info > Submit.

[image]